# ¿Cómo solucionar conflictos entre 2 tablas relacionados con el COLLATION en SQL SERVER 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo problemas para verificar si los campos de dos tablas coinciden en tipo (ambos son de características idénticas , misma cantidad de columnas), a decir verdad una de las tablas es la copia de la otra.

Pero me piden de todas maneras que verifique si los tipos de datos de cada columna (data_type) coinciden en ambas tablas, de modo que hice la siguiente consulta:

```
select t1.column_name, 
case when t1.data_type COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = t2.data_type COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT then t1.data_type else 'diferentes' end data_type
from BD1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t1 inner join BD2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t2
    on (t1.table_name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT =t2.table_name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT)
where t1.TABLE_NAME='MI_TABLA'
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero su pronta respuesta para poder solucionar este problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Establece con que collation quieres efectuar la comparación.

En realidad basta con que lo pongas en la que no se corresponde con la que tiene por defecto el servidor.

Puedes obtener esta información directamente de `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLLATION_NAME`

```
SELECT t1.COLUMN_NAME, 
CASE WHEN t1.DATA_TYPE = t2.DATA_TYPE COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT 
     THEN t1.DATA_TYPE ELSE 'diferentes' END DATA_TYPE
FROM BD1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t1 
     INNER JOIN BD2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t2
         ON (t1.TABLE_NAME = t2.TABLE_NAME COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT)
         AND (t1.COLUM_NAME = t2.COLUMN_NAME COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT)
WHERE t1.TABLE_NAME = 'MI_TABLA';
```

**UPDATE**

Faltaba en INNER JOIN igualar, además de el nombre de la tabla, el nombre de la columna.

Si te fijas he puesto el COLLATE solo en un lado de la igualdad.

Comment: Me sale el mismo error, incluso si pongo el tipo de Sistema de caracteres "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" o "Modern_Spanish_CI_AS" en vez de DATABASE_DEFAULT

Comment: @Fran.J si, debes añadirlo tambien a data_type, lo he probado con dos de mis servidores con collate distintos y funciona.

Comment: Gracias si funciona, me faltó poner también en la linea del `CASE`. Pero tengo otro inconveniente, le he agregado al final un `WHERE` para especificarle la tabla que se va a comparar. y me arroja una cantidad exorbitante (78961) cuando mi tabla solo tiene 281 columnas.

Comment: ya lo modifiqué, creo que el error está en los campos que estoy usando para hacer el `INNER JOIN` con la otra tabla

Comment: Ok, me olvidé de ese detalle, ya está modificado, pero tengo problemas con la cantidad de columnas que salen en el resultado.

Comment: Gracias, para poner el `COLLATE` elijo uno de los lados no más, ¿Cualquiera de ellos?

Comment: Preferiblemente el del servidor vinculado. Pero bueno, si no funciona en uno funcionará en el otro.

Comment: Gracias, una última consulta, soy nuevo en SQL Server, ¿Por qué no es suficiente indicarle en el `JOIN` solamente la columna del `data_type`?

Comment: Porque lo que estas comparando columnas con el mismo nombre, si tienen el mismo tipo o no.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas comparar directamente los tipos de dato declarados en cada columna, puedes utilizar el siguiente *script* donde por medio de la claúsula `EXCEPT` te mostrará las diferencias entre la definición de esas dos tablas:

```
SELECT
    C0.Name AS 'Columna', C0.system_type_id AS 'Id del tipo de dato', t.name AS 'Nombre del tipo de dato'
FROM sys.tables T0
    INNER JOIN sys.columns C0
        ON (T0.object_id = C0.object_id AND T0.Name = 'TablaCero')
    INNER JOIN sys.types t 
        ON t.system_type_id = C0.system_type_id
EXCEPT
SELECT
    C1.Name AS 'Columna', C1.system_type_id AS 'Id del tipo de dato', t.name AS 'Nombre del tipo de dato'
FROM sys.tables T1
    INNER JOIN sys.columns C1
        ON (T1.object_id = C1.object_id AND T1.Name = 'TablaUno')
    INNER JOIN sys.types t 
        ON t.system_type_id = C1.system_type_id
```

Nota: si el *query* no te trae resultados, significa que no hay ninguna diferencia, es decir, las dos tablas tienen la misma definición

Caso contrario, utilizando la claúsula `INTERSECT` podras encontrar aquellas similitudes:

```
SELECT
    C0.Name AS 'Columna', C0.system_type_id AS 'Id del tipo de dato', t.name AS 'Nombre del tipo de dato'
FROM sys.tables T0
    INNER JOIN sys.columns C0
        ON (T0.object_id = C0.object_id AND T0.Name = 'TablaCero')
    INNER JOIN sys.types t 
        ON t.system_type_id = C0.system_type_id
INTERSECT
SELECT
    C1.Name AS 'Columna', C1.system_type_id AS 'Id del tipo de dato', t.name AS 'Nombre del tipo de dato'
FROM sys.tables T1
    INNER JOIN sys.columns C1
        ON (T1.object_id = C1.object_id AND T1.Name = 'TablaUno')
    INNER JOIN sys.types t 
        ON t.system_type_id = C1.system_type_id
```

Comment: Me sigue saliendo el error del `COLLATE` , el mismo mensaje que indico en mi pregunta de este tema. Respecto a este código lo que hice fue anteponer las BD's respectivas en cada bloque que separa el `EXCEPT` y poner el nombre de la tabla a evaluar, en mi caso llevan el mismo nombre, aunque no sé si estuvo bien hacerlo.

Comment: Bien, hagamos lo siguiente, ¿podrías poner la estructura de las dos tablas? Esto es para replicar el escenario que actualmente estás presentando y con eso estoy seguro que solucionamos el problema

Comment: ¿Cómo lo haría?, tiene 281 campos, digamos que se llama TAB_ATENCION y está en una BD_1, la otra tiene el mismo nombre y estructura, (es la copia) solo que con menos registros y en otra base de datos, BD_2, algunos datos adicionales al respecto son que ambas bases de datos están en la misma instancia, BD_2 posee 14 tablas, todas copias idénticas en estructura y denominación que las existentes en BD_1, pero en BD_1 existen más de 40 tablas. BD_2 es una pequeña muestra de BD_1 que se creó para una aplicación determinada.

Comment: EL problema que tengo es con el `COLLATE` cuando hago las comparaciones de cada campo en los esquemas correspondientes a cada base de datos.

Comment: Pero en la consulta que te pongo ya no necesitas el `COLLATE` ya que compara directamente los tipos de dato de cada tabla

Comment: Pero tengo que especificar de que base de datos estoy sacando la información, como te decía, las tablas están en distintas bases de datos, y estas tienen distinta intercalación.. y pues si, me sale el mensaje de conflicto de intercalación cuando especifico las bases de datos en el código que me has mandado.